# VBE Auto-corrects with Semi-colons

Tags: excel, vba

I was playing with the VBE's VBA to see if any of the more esoteric logical operators from VB.Net were operational.

> <sub>**IsNot** is the opposite of the Is operator. The advantage of IsNot is that you can avoid awkward syntax with Not and Is, which can be difficult to read.
> [IsNot Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/isnot-operator)</sub>

For kicks and giggles, I typed this into a public module code sheet.

```
Sub test()

    dim obj As object

    debug.print obj isnot nothing

End Sub
```

As soon as I hit *<enter>* after typing the code line *debug.print obj nothing* the VBE auto-corrected¹ itself to this.

```
Sub test()

    Dim obj As Object

    Debug.Print obj; isnot; Nothing

End Sub
```

Oh-key-doh-key, `isnot` wasn't recognized and I get that. It's not part of VB7.

What I cannot understand is the inclusion of semi-colons by the VBE's auto-correct system.

What is a semi-colon's purpose in VBA script?

---

¹ <sub>Real programmers use COPY CON</sub>

Comment: This is useful to know. When I've wanted to `Debug.Print` two values, I have always used something like `Debug.Print val1 & ", " & val2`. It seems that just typing `Debug.Print val1 val2` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the syntax for [`Debug.Print`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/print-method).

> `object.Print [ outputlist ]`
>
> The outputlist argument has the following syntax and parts: `{Spc(n) | Tab(n)} expression charpos`
>
> *charpos*
>   Optional. Specifies the insertion point for the next character. **Use a semicolon (;) to position the insertion point immediately following the last character displayed.**

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the output of these 2

```
Debug.Print "aa", "bb", 1, 2
Debug.Print "aa"; "bb"; 1; 2
```

While the comma ends up in a tab the semicolon appends them directly (without spacing).
Numeric values obviously get enclosed in spaces `_1_` that's why between characters and numbers there is 1 space and between 2 numbers there are 2 spaces.

[image]